# How to call helper function in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel 5.5. I have created a helper.php in app\Http. I am calling this helper in my blade file by using

```
{!! Helper::functionName() !!}
```

this is working fine. but i want to hold this helper result in a variable like

```
{!! $Result=Helper::functionName() !!}
```

But currently this is printing this result. How to solve this. please help.
So that i can make any if condition on this $Result.

In my helpers.php

```
namespace App\Http\Helpers;

class Helper
{
    public static function functionName()
    {
       return "mydata";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no point to use helper like this. You should run the helper in controller and pass calculated data into view. In most cases you shouldn't set any variables in views or make any calculations - those should be passed from controller to view and view should only use them.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use `"<?php  ?>"`.
So result:
`<?php $Result=Helper::functionName(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

may be this is not possible because in laravel "{{}}" this means echo "" so by default it will print the value. return the value from helper function and use in your blade